# centro de software de ubuntu 20 me muestra un error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

en centro de software de ubuntu 20 me muestra el error de la imagen adjunta,aunque funciona bien quiero solucionar este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no es un problema "grave" quizas sea algun tema de permismos, pero puedes intentar lo siguiente.

- Abre el monitor del sistema y busca "snap-store"
- Mata el proceso
- Re abre el centro de software